# How to calculate the overlap between 2 dataset distribution

Tags: r, integration, montecarlo

Hi How can calculate the overlapping area between 2 columns ( or 2 subsets of a column) in R.
Please see the example data below:

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
  Data=factor(rep(c("D1", "D2"), each=200)),
  weight=round(c(rnorm(200, mean=55, sd=5),
                 rnorm(200, mean=65, sd=5)))
)

library(ggplot2)
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(weight,fill = Data))+
  geom_density() 
plot
```

This results in the below plot. I am wondering, how to color the overlapping area and calculate the overlapping coefficient (OVL) similar to what is done [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/01/calculating-the-overlap-of-two-normal-distributions-using-monte-carlo-integration/) Using Monte Carlo Integration?
Please note that the link (and example above) provided uses parametric distribution while I am asking if I have a dataset of observed values.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I normally find it easier to work directly with the densities and plot them as `geom_area`. If you get the x-axis sampling points to match on the two distributions you can find the overlap area using `pmin`, and the sum of its values divided by the sum of the values for the two curves should give you the proportion of the total area that is overlapped.

```r
d1dens <- with(df, density(weight[Data == "D1"], 
                           from = min(weight), 
                           to = max(weight)))
d2dens <- with(df, density(weight[Data == "D2"], 
                           from = min(weight),
                           to = max(weight)))
joint <- pmin(d1dens$y, d2dens$y)

df2 <- data.frame(x = rep(d1dens$x, 3), 
                  y = c(d1dens$y, d2dens$y, joint),
                  Data = rep(c("D1", "D2", "overlap"), each = length(d1dens$x)))

ggplot(df2, aes(x, y, fill = Data)) + 
  geom_area(position = position_identity(), color = "black") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel2") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

```r
sum(joint) / sum(d1dens$y, d2dens$y)
#> [1] 0.1480701
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. one comment, for the calculation of the overlapping coefficient, wouldn't it be `(sum(joint)/sum(d1dens$y) + sum(joint)/sum(d2dens$y))/2`